Issue with RegionFunction as an option in ListContourPlot
I've come across an issue using the RegionFunction option in the ListContourPlot function. The issue is illustrated in the notebook that I've published on Wolfram Community - see https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/3244538. I've defined a (concave) boundary mesh region for a set of points and I want to use the boundary mesh to restrict the display of contours such that the contours only appear within the mesh region. However, the functionality does not seem to be working as I expect it to. I've tried using a different region (i.e. a Disk) to confine the display of contours. And that does work as expected.
Having tried a few things, I eventually found a rather unsatisfactory workaround - scroll down to the penultimate section of the aforementioned notebook. Whilst the workaround is far from ideal, it does at least give the desired result. And seems to suggest that there may be a bug in the way that RegionFunction option is working in ListContourPlot.
However, I'm still not wholly convinced that I'm not doing something wrong and would welcome any comments/suggestions. Especially from Wolfram insiders who might be able to confirm whether or not there's a bug.
Thank in anticipation...
